# Why shouldn't use arrow functions for declaring stateless components in react?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, components, arrow-functions, stateless

according to Airbnb React style guide, It's better to use a normal function for declaring stateless component, rather than use an Arrow function. 
My question is why a normal function is better?
[image]
https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#class-vs-reactcreateclass-vs-stateless

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Airbnb style guide say that relying on function name inference is discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288950/why-does-the-airbnb-style-guide-say-that-relying-on-function-name-inference-is-d)

Comment: ^This will answer your question.

Comment: @jibin-joseph Thanks a lot it's really useful, but I couldn't understand the accepted answer deeply, I need more explanation about this concept.

Comment: @SamaneYaghoobi This is a full dupe indeed. I've posted an answer and tried to keep it straight and simple, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55784719/3731501