# What is the difference between arrow functions and regular functions inside React functional components (no longer using class components)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Since React Hooks, I have decided to let go of React class components. I'm only dealing with hooks and functional components now.

**Simple question:**

I understand the difference between using an arrow function instead of a regular function inside of a class body. The arrow function would automatically bind (***lexical this***) to the instance of my class and I don't have to bind it in the constructor. This is nice.

But since I'm not dealing with classes anymore, I would like to know what is the difference of doing the following inside of a functional component:

```
function App() {

  // REGULAR FUNCTION
  function handleClick1() {
    console.log('handleClick1 executed...');
  }

  // ARROW FUNCTION
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    console.log('handleClick2 executed...');
  }

  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={'div1'} onClick={handleClick1}>
        Div 1 - Click me
      </div>
      <div className={'div2'} onClick={handleClick2}>
        Div 2 - Click me
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

**QUESTION**

Both works fine.

Is there a **difference in performance?** Should I favor **one way instead of the other?** They're **both recreated on every render, correct?**

---

**NOTE ON POSSIBLE DUPLICATES**

I really don't think this is a duplicate question. I know there are plenty of questions about the difference between arrows and regulars, but I want to know from the perspective of a React functional component and how React handles with it. I've looked around and didn't find one.

---

**CODE SNIPPET FOR TESTING**

```js
function App() {
  
  function handleClick1() {
    console.log('handleClick1 executed...');
  }
  
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    console.log('handleClick2 executed...');
  }
  
  return(
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={'div1'} onClick={handleClick1}>
        Div 1 - Click me
      </div>
      <div className={'div2'} onClick={handleClick2}>
        Div 2 - Click me
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.div1 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.div2 {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  cursor: pointer;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: If you're not using `this` then the difference is completely irrelevant inside the function. The difference outside is that function declarations are hoisted to the top of the scope, assigning an arrow function to a variable (var, const, let) is not. There's a further difference in how var differs from const and let, but that only matters if you reference something before it's assigned.

Comment: Whatever other info you've read about arrow functions vs regular named functions vs anonymous functions declared with variables still applies here. [There is no performance difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44031830/8237835) between them. And it's not even possible to detect if a function is an arrow function at runtime so React doesn't and can't handle them differently than regular functions.

Comment: Per the earlier comment see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname/338053).

Comment: Oof. I was wrong about not being able to detect arrow functions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28222228/javascript-es6-test-for-arrow-function-built-in-function-regular-function but I highly doubt React is doing that anyway. Mostly because of transpilers being a thing.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/55784719/3731501

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beside the differences you've already pointed out (lexical scope), arrow functions (and function expressions) are **not** hoisted, and as such cannot be called before they are defined. See my example. This is in my opinion not a problem, since code that relies on hoisting is much harder to reason about.

React really doesn't care about which one you use (nor can it detect it).

```js
const A = () => {
  const name = getName();
  
  function getName() {
    return 'praffn';
  }
  
  // Will not work
  // const getName = () => 'praffn';
  
  return <p>Hi, {name}</p>;
}

ReactDOM.render(<A/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Personally I haven't found function hoisting to be much of an issue in practice (unlike `var` hoisting) and I think having the `function` keyword there makes the code more readable than it would be with nearly everything starting with `const`. (I suspect Facebook might have similar reasons for using `function` in their examples.) But as Phillip already pointed out, this is a stylistic preference—either will work fine.

Comment: @MattBrowne, I actually prefer using the `function` keyword - to me it is much more readable. I usually only use arrow functions for one-liners and when used in higher order functions. I do however refrain from relying on hoisting when possible.

Comment: @MattBrowne I think that the `function` keyword makes the code more readable too. And I hardly ever use the hoisting "feature".

Answer (score 5):

Since you are not accessing the `this` context, both will both behave **the same**.

To understand more, you can check how babel is transpiring to the ECMA:

```
 const handleClick2 = () => {
    console.log('handleClick2 executed...');
    this.x=3
 }
```

will be transpiled as:

```
"use strict";

var _this = void 0;

var handleClick2 = function handleClick2() {
  console.log('handleClick2 executed...');
  _this.x = 3;
};
```

[Link to babel notepad](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=AQYw9gdgzgLsAWBDCATANgUwMJoJYgGsAmYAXmAAoBKMgPmAG8AoYV0SKMTAOjTAHMKAciSpMOfMWAYAHhhABXGBhTc1QqgG4WbGPFxRuM0gGYWAXyA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.4&externalPlugins=)

Comment: Accessing `this` inside of an arrow function or function declaration will not give any difference since `this` will be equal to `undefined`. This is because `React components are written within ES6 modules, which automatically run in strict mode`.